# Fetch by mulitple record ordering with custom fields

Tags: mysql

I have some problem in fetching records with multiple ordering. For this i have write query but problem is that, in one ordering i have custom fields. I want to order by custom values and normal ordering both.

// Query

```
select id, name, f_name, catg, form_no, address, mobile, grp, prt_no, reg_amt, adm_chg,
       flat_detail
from mst_app
where mobile = ?
order by block,level,flat_no
```

I want to add custom value on level column.

Any one can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "custom fields?"  Can you show some sample data along with the desired output?

Comment: Sure in "Level" column I have four value. I want to order it by my own choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want conditional order by for level column.. Then you can use case function...

```
ORDER BY 
CASE
   WHEN level <> 0 THEN level  
END desc
```

Comment: got it here is the solution select id, name, f_name, catg, form_no, address, mobile, grp, prt_no, reg_amt, adm_chg, flat_detail from mst_app where mobile = ? order by block,FIELD(LEVEL , 'GF', 'FF', 'SF', 'TF') ,flat_no